# Java installer issue on windows 10

Tags: java, java-8, windows-10, installation

I wanted to install simple JAVA JDK on it (that's 8u131 version downloaded from oracle's site). 
The problem is my installer doesn't work, this is it doesn't run, with no popping information, like it ignores the information about executing. Then I updated windows and graphics card but nothing's changed. Got no idea what's wrong. I've also tried different installers, downloading on a different pc and then executing it here, tried to install older versions of JDK but there was always no reaction from the program. Do you have any ideas how to fix it ?

Thank you for your help.

@Edit
I also have just the same problem with eclipse installer.

Comment: have you tried to take it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Are you allowed to install software on the machine?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Steam works, so I guess yes

Comment: If everything is updated properly, you most likely have a Windows configuration problem and/or insufficient rights.  Ask on superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete reinstall of windows (disk included) helped. Thanks a lot my friends. :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you download the version of JDK corresponding to your version of OS (windows 32bit(86) vs 64bit). If you still face this issue, just try restarting the machine (its windows, so why not?) Jokes apart, sometimes it may help. If the issue is still there, just keep an eye on the system process after a restart and then run the installer and check whether you see any new process or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is strange. I suggest you to disable your antivirus, firewall and run the program again. Also have a look at Task Manager and search for the program in processes.

Lastly, reboot your system and enter safe mode. Try running the program again. If the program pops in safe mode then maybe sth is blocking it in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

What is "doesn't work"? Have you tried type "java" or "java --version" into terminal (cmd)?
Like this:

> C:\Users\EeeMt>java -version
> java version "1.8.0_72"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)

And if you got:

> C:\Users\EeeMt>java
> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

You should check your system environment variable.
[image: system environment variable]

#### configure system environment variable

1. new variable "JAVA_HOME"
   [image: new variable "JAVA_HOME"]
2. add to "Parh"[image]

to check the environment variable in CMD, you should restart the CMD

Comment: Yes, I did actually reinstalled the whole windows and updated it again. Nothing seems to work. But I see that problem can truly be in lack of java enviroment as I got the second answer( @mt eee method) from cmd. Unfortunetely I don't understand what should I type at "Edit Variable Enviroment" window, which is shown last. I mean I've typed it just like mt eee did this and I still don't have the "JAVA_HOME" in my system variables. Can someone explain me this a bit clearer ? Thank you!

Comment: @skorejen I have update the answer, hope it will be helpful and good lucky.

Comment: I see the problem seems much worse than it looks, as I mentioned I have not yet installed any java softwere, so I have no path to type in the "variable value"...

Comment: @skorejen so, install a suitable jdk,

Comment: this is the case, I can't do it hah

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need to reinstall the Windows.

Normally on diretory : 
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java

you have one file (among the symb links) with name **java.settings.cfg**.

The contents of this file for me was :

```
AUTO_UPDATE=0
INSTALL_SILENT=1
NOSTARTMENU=1
SPONSORS=0
```

If you change parameter **install_silent**  INSTALL_SILENT=0 you can install the java normally.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

How to Install Java SE:

Go to the link - https://jdk.java.net/13/ or https://jdk.java.net/14/ for version 13 and 14 respectively.
Click on OpenJDK Archive.
For windows-[Windows 64-bit zip (sha256) 187M], Download the zip file
Extract the Zip file and move the complete folder to C:\Program Files\Java
List item
Set the environment variable for your system, Go to Control Panel > System and Security > System >Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > User Variables for Admin, select NEW Enter variable name = Path Variable Value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin Click ok - ok -ok
Check for installed Java SE- Open command prompt Type java -version (You will get details of your installed java version)

- List item

Comment: The O/P solved this 3+ years ago.  What does your answer add?